# How to convert a vector of chategorial data to a dataframe or matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector

I have this dataset:

```
ID <- c("0001", "0003", "0002","0004","0005")
YourName <- c("Juan", "Pedro", "Ana", "Alejandra","Alex")
GenderPeople <- c("Male","Male","Female","Female","Male")

DF <- data.frame(ID, YourName, GenderPeople)
```

I want to convert column "GenderPeople" into a matrix (or dataframe) that looks like this:

```
    ID  YourName GenderPeople_Male GenderPeople_Female
  0001      Juan                 1                   0
  0003     Pedro                 1                   0
  0002       Ana                 0                   1
  0004 Alejandra                 0                   1
  0005      Alex                 1                   0
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `spread` after creating a column of 1s

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  mutate(n = 1, GenderPeople = str_c("GenderPeople", GenderPeople, sep="_")) %>% 
  spread(GenderPeople, n, fill = 0)
#     ID  YourName GenderPeople_Female GenderPeople_Male
#1 0001      Juan                   0                 1
#2 0002       Ana                   1                 0
#3 0003     Pedro                   0                 1
#4 0004 Alejandra                   1                 0
#5 0005      Alex                   0                 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dummies)

dummy.data.frame(DF, names = "GenderPeople", sep = "_")

#     ID  YourName GenderPeople_Female GenderPeople_Male
# 1 0001      Juan                   0                 1
# 2 0003     Pedro                   0                 1
# 3 0002       Ana                   1                 0
# 4 0004 Alejandra                   1                 0
# 5 0005      Alex                   0                 1
```

Comment: Not sure if `dummy` can return the rest of the columns. It works like `dummy("GenderPeople", data=DF)` or `dummy(DF$GenderPeople)`.

Comment: I checked the documentation.  Looks like these are separate functions and not method dispatch